# Using RDiscount, where should I do the actual formatting?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, rdiscount

I'm using RDiscount but my Ruby on Rails skills are limited. RDiscount has its .to_html function which converts the Markdown text into HTML. So here's the scenario:

`<% @posts.each do |post| %>

    <h3><%= post.title %></h3>

    <%= post.content %>

<% end %>`

post.content is what I want to convert to html.

1) Where should I create a method to convert the string into HTML?
2) How do I stop RoR from escaping the HTML that RDiscount.to_html returns?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

1) Preferably, in a helper
2) By calling [html_safe](http://yehudakatz.com/2010/02/01/safebuffers-and-rails-3-0/) on the resulting string

I have not used markdown in a Rails 3 app, which escapes content by default, but created a helper similar to the `h` method prior Rails 3, which converted the markdown to html. The approach for Rails 3 would be something like

```
module Helper
  def m(string)
    RDiscount.new(string).to_html.html_safe
  end
end
```

in the view

```
<% @posts.each do |post| %>
  <h3><%= post.title %></h3>
  <%= m post.content %>
<% end %>
```